# Handling JSON data with no identifiers

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and javascript so if this is obvious I apologize. 
I have a set of data that works in Flot but I seem to be having trouble getting it to recognize in d3, it is json with no identifiers. Such as

```
{
"dataLine": [ [134, 43.39], [144, 45.34], [154, 47.45], [164, 48.25], [174, 48.14], [184, 48.21], [194, 47.64], [204, 47.58], [214, 52.18], [224, 58.18], [234, 53.19], [244, 61.28], [254, 56.50], [264, 53.92], [274, 57.27], [284, 58.73], [294, 57.28], [304, 52.91], [314, 55.07], [324, 60.58], [334, 61.16], [344, 62.64], [354, 60.39], [364, 62.79], [372, 65.24] ]
}
```

I can get the data to work if I add the "x" and "y" tags before each entry, but how would I handle the data without the tags? Assuming the first entry is the "x" and the second entry is "y". The code I am currently using is

```
d3.json('3.json', function (data) 
{
 data.forEach(function(d) 
 {
   d.x = d.x;
   d.y = d.y;
 });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area);
  //.attr("d", valueline);


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Force (N)");
});
```

And the data looks like

```
 [
  {"x":134, "y":43.39}, {"x":144, "y":45.34}, {"x":154, "y":47.45}, {"x":164,"y":48.25}, {"x":174, "y":48.14}, {"x":184, "y":48.21}, {"x":194, "y":47.64},  {"x":204, "y":47.58}, {"x":214, "y":52.18}, {"x":224, "y":58.18}, {"x":234, "y":53.19}, {"x":244, "y":61.28}, {"x":254, "y":56.50}, {"x":264, "y":53.92}, {"x":274, "y":57.27}, {"x":284, "y":58.73}, {"x":294, "y":57.28}, {"x":304, "y":52.91}, {"x":314, "y":55.07}, {"x":324, "y":60.58}, {"x":334, "y":61.16}, {"x":344, "y":62.64}, {"x":354, "y":60.39}, {"x":364, "y":62.79}, {"x":372, "y":65.24} 
 ]
```

I can graph it like this but all my historical data is like the first example, I know I am doing something wrong as I am just following tutorials and examples blindly at the moment and any help or hints are greatly appreciated. So to make it simple, is there a way to graph the first set of data I have posted? If yes then let me take it further, how would I graph that entry "dataLine" and I also have 5+ other entries in the same json file to graph that are formatted the same way but with different tags?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle from it? I think it is easier to correct that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first question, there is no need to re-format your data.  `d3` provides [accessor functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_x) to take data in different formats.  In your case, for arrays of arrays, you'd need:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d[0]; // this really should be x(d[0]) when you properly use scales
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d[1]; // this really should be y(d[0]) when you properly use scales
    })
```

And you'd bind to:

```
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data.valueLine);
```

Your second question is a little more difficult.  For this you are looking at using a [subselection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#subselections).  Say your data is:

```
var data = {
    "dataLine1": [
      [134, 43.39],
      [144, 45.34],
      ...
    ],
    "dataLine2": [
      [224, 58.18],
      [234, 53.19],
      ...
    ],
    "dataLine3": [
      [324, 60.58],
      [334, 61.16],
      ...
    ]
  };
```

And you want a line for each `dataLine`.  First bind your data for each line:

```
var myLines = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.values(data)) // get me an array of 3 arrays
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "line");
```

Then create the subselection to create each path:

```
myLines.append("path")
    .datum(function(d){
      return d; // just return me the array!
    })
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", valueline) // using the accessor functions above
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke",function(d,i,j){
      return color(i);
    });
```

Here's some working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>

      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 500)
        .attr('height', 500);

      var data = {
        "dataLine1": [
          [134, 43.39],
          [144, 45.34],
          [154, 47.45],
          [164, 48.25],
          [174, 48.14],
          [184, 48.21],
          [194, 47.64],
          [204, 47.58],
          [214, 52.18]
        ],
        "dataLine2": [
          [224, 58.18],
          [234, 53.19],
          [244, 61.28],
          [254, 56.50],
          [264, 53.92],
          [274, 57.27],
          [284, 58.73],
          [294, 57.28],
          [304, 52.91],
          [314, 55.07]
        ],
        "dataLine3": [
          [324, 60.58],
          [334, 61.16],
          [344, 62.64],
          [354, 60.39],
          [364, 62.79],
          [372, 65.24]
        ]
      };
      
      var color = d3.scale.category10();
      
      var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return d[0];
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return d[1];
        });

      var myLines = svg.selectAll("line")
        .data(d3.values(data))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "line");
        
      myLines.append("path")
        .datum(function(d){
          return d;
        })
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", valueline)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke",function(d,i,j){
          return color(i);
        });

  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Going to try this out and will get back as soon as I can, I appreciate the help! I have been going crazy :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have managed to get it to work within my code, although I have to figure out formatting and scale, I believe I can figure it out! Again, thanks!